# FIR filter length is the intercept included as a coefficient?-- Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, terminology, moving-average

I have some confusion about the terminologies and simulation of an FIR system. I shall appreciate help in rectifying my mistakes and informing what is correct.

Assuming a FIR filter with coefficient array `A=[1,c2,c3,c4]`. The number of elements are `L` so the length of the filter `L` but the order is `L-1`.

**Confusion1:** Is the intercept `1` considered as a coefficient? Is it always 1?

**Confusion2:** Is my understanding correct that for the given example the length `L= 4` and `order=3`?

**Confusion3:** Mathematically, I can write it as:

[image: x[n] = \sum_{l=0}^{L-1}A_l u[n-l]]

where `u` is the input data and `l` starts from zero. Then to simulate the above equation I have done the following convolution. Is it correct?:

```
N =100; %number of data
A = [1, 0.1, -0.5, 0.62];
u = rand(1,N);
x(1) = 0.0;
x(2) = 0.0;
x(3) = 0.0;
x(4) = 0.0;
for n = 5:N
    x(n) = A(1)*u(n) + A(2)*u(n-1)+ A(3)*u(n-3)+ A(4)*u(n-4);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Confusion1:** Is the intercept `1` considered as a coefficient? Is it always 1?

Yes it is considered a coefficient, and no it isn't always 1. It is very common to include a global scaling factor in the coefficient array by multiplying all the coefficients (i.e. scaling the input or output of a filter with coefficients `[1,c1,c2,c2]` by `K` is equivalent to using a filter with coefficients `[K,K*c1,K*c2,K*c3]`). Also note that many FIR filter design techniques generate coefficients whose amplitude peaks near the middle of the coefficient array and taper off at the start and end.

> **Confusion2:** Is my understanding correct that for the given example the length `L= 4` and order = 3?

Yes, that is correct

> **Confusion3:** *[...]*  Then to simulate the above equation I have done the following convolution. Is it correct? *[...]*

Almost, but not quite. Here are the few things that you need to fix.

1. In the main `for` loop, applying the formula you would increment the index of `A` and decrement the index of `u` by 1 for each term, so you would actually get `x(n) = A(1)*u(n) + A(2)*u(n-1)+ A(3)*u(n-2)+ A(4)*u(n-3)`
2. You can actually start this loop at `n=4`
3. The first few outputs should still be using the formula, but dropping the terms `u(n-k)` for which `n-k` would be less than 1. So, for `x(3)` you'd be dropping 1 term, for `x(2)` you'd be dropping 2 terms and for `x(1)` you'd be dropping 3 terms.

The modified code would look like the following:

```
x(1)=A(1)*u(1);
x(2)=A(1)*u(2) + A(2)*u(1);
x(3)=A(1)*u(3) + A(2)*u(2) + A(3)*u(1);
for n = 4:N
  x(n) = A(1)*u(n) + A(2)*u(n-1)+ A(3)*u(n-2)+ A(4)*u(n-3);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is very helpful. Just to confirm if I have followed your answer correctly, 1) if `h=[1,0.2,0.3]` then is the order is 2 and length is 3?(2)There is also another term known as `lag` for AR and MA models.  Is order = lag?

Comment: 1) yes. 2) For  MA, `lag = order/2` samples (aka `order/(2*Fs)` seconds if `Fs` is the sampling frequency in Hz). For others (non linear-phase MA, and AR) the relationship isn't that trivial. To quote the [linear-phase article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_phase), "A filter with linear phase may be achieved by an FIR filter which is either symmetric or anti-symmetric."